# custom spinner with dynamic objects and dynamic icons

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-widget, android-arrayadapter

currently i'm trying to get a custom spinner to work. It uses a custom layout and the arrayadapter of it gets filled by custom objects. now i want a icon to appear next to every object in the spinner.

so far i use code that looks like this:

```
    // create spinner
    logicSpinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.logicSpinner);
    logicAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<SearchLogic>(parent, R.layout.icon_spinner_layout, R.id.typesfield, myLogics);
    logicSpinner.setAdapter(logicAdapter);
```

where myLogics provides a ArrayList with types of SearchLogic. The SearchLogic class looks like this

```
public class SearchLogic {

    private String  otherString;
    private String  localString;
    private int     imageRes;

    public SearchLogic(String otherString, String localString, int imageRes){
        this.otherString = otherString;
        this.localString = localString;
        this.imageRes = imageRes;

    }
    /*
     * let's override the toString method since thats the method a spinner object uses as default value for its entries
     */
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return this.localString;
    }
```

The icon_spinner_layout looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ObjectSpecificIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/typesfield"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

now i'm creating a new SearchLogic object and adding it to myLogics like so:

```
myLogics.add(new SearchLogic("string1", "string2", R.drawable.iconXYZ));
```

and i would like that "ObjectSpecificIcon" is filled with the icon passed to the SearchLogic object. How to do that? is it possible to provide a "placeholder" within the layout.xml file instead of providing a hard-coded src? or any other way?

Comment: got something going on guys. found a way to do it but its still not working as i wish. i will tell you when i hunt the last problems down and post the code here then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is how its done: [Method for Spinner  item click listener with SimpleCursorAdapter and ViewBinder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030417/method-for-spinner-listener-item-click-with-simplecrusoradapter-viewbinder)

basicly you have to use a custom ViewBinder for the Array / CursorAdapter. See my own answer to get the final problems i had while implementing it resolved.