# Method for Spinner  item click listener with SimpleCursorAdapter and ViewBinder

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner, android-viewbinder

I got a `Spinner` element which I populate with data from a `Cursor` using a `SimpleCursorAdapter`. Also I'm using `setViewBinder` for a custom row layout of the `Spinner`. Everything works out fine, the `Spinner` gets the data and the `Spinner` items use the custom layout.

But clicking the items from the `Spinner` drop down view **doesn't do anything**. It doesn't set the selected item as selected and doesn't close the drop down view. I don't know what I have to do so the selected item from the list is passed to the `Spinner` logic and runs like it should. Here's the layout I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="#424242"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Textfield" />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and here's the `ViewBinder`:

```
static final ViewBinder VIEW_BINDER = new ViewBinder(){
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex){

        if (view.getId() == R.id.text){

            String local = view.getResources().getString(cursor.getInt(columnIndex));
            ((TextView) view).setText( local );

            return true;
        }
        if (view.getId() == R.id.icon){

            int icon = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
            ((ImageView) view).setImageResource(icon);

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
};
```

and here's how I add the data to the `Spinner`:

```
private Spinner spinner;
private DBHandler dbhandler;
private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
private final String[] from = new String[]{dbhandler.LIB_LOCAL, dbhandler.LIB_ICON};
private final int[] to = { R.id.text, R.id.icon };  
@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    Cursor cursor = dbhandler.getLibEntries();


    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_row, cursor, from, to);
    adapter.setViewBinder(VIEW_BINDER);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Adding a `OnItemSelectedListener` like suggested down in this post was implemented like below, but doesn't solve the problem. Also I'm not sure how the `setOnItemSelectedListener` could help me to get the data fields I need later on:

```
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        });
```

[image: the problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here we go:

its neccessary to set `adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_row);`
the DropDownView defines the look of the DropDownView and the layout defined in the SimpleCursorAdapter constructor defines the layout of the items of the (closed) spinner object itself (not its drop down view!).

so, its nice to have a different layout for the DropDownView which is exacly like the one defined in the SimpleCursorAdapter so the values pushed to it can be set to the right corresponding fields except with the difference that i use `android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"` for the textview of the dropdownview layout and android:layout_height="wrap_content" for the textview of the spinner layout!

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is implement an [OnItemSelectedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemSelectedListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener%29). In the listener, when ever an item is selected save that item to some sort of variable you can access after the spinner is closed.

Comment: well, its not a custom spinner, its just using a custom view for its items. when using a standard spinner the selection is implemented whether a listener is set or not. i dont want any special activity to perform but only that i'm able to select a item and the dropdown closes and the selected item is returned when i call getSelectedItem(). is it neccessary that i use a own listener for that? + if so, what do i have to call that the dropdown gets closed and the item selected?

Comment: well, i set a OnItemSelectedListener. But thats not the problem. the thing is that --> its not possible <-- to select a item from the dropdown list. the only thing i can do is add a onClick to the layout, BUT theres no way how that event could ever reach the spinner. i edited some more code and an image to make it more clear.

Comment: Oooooooooooo. I understand now. That's a weird problem.